# How to convert string to date in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a table in SAS where in one column, the date is stored (e.g. "2005/10").
How do I have to convert this to a SAS data format?

Among many other tries, I tried this code:

data test;

```
        format date YYMMS.;

        date = input(ObservationMonth, YYMMS.);

        put date=date9.;

run;
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Questions which can easily be answered by consulting documentation are generally considered low-quality. Can you point to a resource which does it incorrectly (and include the code)? What error message did you get when you tried it?

Comment: I'm sorry jpaugh that this question can be answered by documentation, I did not find one that matches my problem! I just tried a lot of code of similar things, e.g. the one I included in the question with the edit.

Comment: @bat post the type and format that your variable currently has. You can find these by running proc contents.

Comment: @Reeza it says char of length 200

Comment: Thanks, bat! Adding a code sample really improves your chances of getting a useful answer. It not only helps us gauge your point-of-view and skill level, but it also shows us that you're willing to work through the problem on your own, as much as you can. (From a practical standpoint, that means an answer only has to correct, rather than fabricate, code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `substr()` and `mdy()` to extract the date components:

```
data _null_;
  ObservationMonth ="2005/10";
  date =mdy(substr(ObservationMonth,6,2),1,substr(ObservationMonth,1,4));
  put date = date9.;
run;
```

Another option is to use the `anydtdte` informat (note that results may differ depending on your locale):

```
data _null_;
  ObservationMonth ="2005/10";
  date =input(ObservationMonth,anydtdte.);
  put date = date9.;
run;
```

Yet another option is to modify the input to enable use of the `YYMMDDw.` informat:

```
data _null_;
  ObservationMonth ="2005/10";
  date =input(ObservationMonth!!'/01', YYMMDD10.);
  put date = date9.;
run;
```

Comment: thanks Allan! If I copy&paste your code, it works, all the three work fine, but if I do it with mine (I have to remove the row "ObservationMonth = "..."; because ObservationMonth is a column of my table) it does not - all three delete all my observations and leave only one column with a dot in each cell. Do you have an idea what mistake I make?

Comment: yes - as @user7728959 advises, remove the line that says `observationMonth` (which was just to show sample data) and add a set statement with your own dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `anydtdte.` informat.

```
data want;
format date yymms.;
text="2005/10";
date=input(text,anydtdte.);
put date;
run;
```

This informat detects most date formattings and converts the character-stored value to a SAS date.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but as I wrote above, SAS deletes all observations and leaves one row with a dot in each cell (I deleted your row "text=..." because ObservationMonth is a column in my table). Do you have an idea what mistake I make?

Comment: Try using a variable name that is NOT in your data set. So the variable name you pass in is your text variable and the name of the variable created is unique.

Comment: In the sample code you posted, you indeed seem to try to convert a variable called `ObservationMonth`, yet there is no `set` statement to provide such a variable. In mine and other answers, we all included a statement such as `variable="2005/10"` because there has to be a value to convert. Without that or a `set` statement, it is very obvious that the result will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

you're fantastic, guys! Thank you so much, with a "set" statement it works fine!